# QTabWidget round corners for frame (not tabs)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtabwidget

How can i make QTabWidget's corners rounded? Not Tab's, but frame's (?)

[image: This corners]

I tried:

```
QTabWidget{
border-radius: 7px;
}
```

But it isn't working.

QSS for tabs:

```
QTabBar::tab {
background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0.5, y1:1, x2:0.5, y2:0, stop:0 rgb(253,250,250), stop:0.2 rgb(253,250,250), stop:1 rgb(255,249,234));

border-top-left-radius: 7px;
border-top-right-radius: 7px;

min-width: 8ex;
padding: 5px;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected {
background-color: rgb(253,250,250);
}

QTabBar::tab:!selected {
margin-top: 5px;
background: qlineargradient(x1:0.5, y1:1, x2:0.5, y2:0, stop:0 rgb(253,250,250), stop:0.2 rgb(253,250,250), stop:1 rgb(250,244,229));
color: rgb(93, 109, 109)
}
```

Comment: Show your stylesheet code in the question please

Comment: @PatrickParker added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested this (black color and thick frame just to see something) and should thus work:

`QTabWidget::pane {border: 3px solid black; border-radius: 7px;}`